# Laravel отношение belongsToMany с двумя ключами и один из них через другое отношение

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

Таблицы sql:

**users**

```
id (ai)
```

**bulletins**

```
id (ai)
owner = user.id
```

**conversations**

```
id (ai)
owner_id = user.id //первый собеседник
bulletin_id = bulletins.id //второй собеседник - тут проблема - не знаю как используя это id получить user.id
```

**модель conversation:**

```
public function bulletin()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Bulletins','bulletin_id');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','owner_id');
}
```

Нужно что бы **users()** вернул коллекцию с обоими юзерами:

```
owner_id = user.id
```

и

```
bulletin_id->owner = user.id
```

И такое же отношение в юзер модели user->conversations:

```
public function conversations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Conversations::class,'owner_id'); //как сюда привязать еще и conversations->bulletin_id = bulletin->owner
}
```

---

```
conversations.owner_id или conversations.bulletin_id->owner = user.id
```

Сейчас я получаю то что нужно вот таким запросом, но это не очень удобно ввиду того что не возвращаются модели и приходится каждый раз их дергать отдельно при необходимости, а нужно именно жадная загрузка

```
$conversations = Conversations::with('bulletin','messages','users')
    ->leftJoin('own', 'conversations.bulletin_id', '=', 'own.id')
    ->select('conversations.*')
    ->where('owner_id', $userId)
    ->orWhere('owner', $userId)
    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

own - это таблица bulletins, в вопросе обозвал ее иначе для наглядности

Comment: А как переводятся на русский `bulletins` и `conversation` в контексте вашего приложения?

Comment: объявления и обсуждения

Comment: Есть продавцы есть покупатели, в обсуждении учавствует 2 человека не больше, один из них точно продавец, второй точно покупатель. owner_id в таблице conversations это покупатель т.е. его user.id. А вот bulletin_id это уже из таблицы bulletins - каждое объявления так же принадлежит определенному user.id. Конечно я мог бы писать оба user.id в таблицу conversations, но мне кажется это не лучшее решение.

Comment: Добавил query которой я сейчас получаю то что нужно, может быть так станет понятней

Comment: messages это отдельная таблица для conversations - каждое обсуждение ведь содержит сообщения разные. Но это в данном случае не имеет никакого значения, messages в этом случае нам точно не нужен )

Comment: с owner проблем никаких нет, проблема с bulletin_id и как через него получить user.id при этом еще и одним запросом вместе с owner_id